# Upload code with formatting

Tags: support, formatting

How can you learn to upload the code step by step with images or videos? The words are hard to translate into something understandable! Does AI artificial intelligence not help?

[image: Screenshot of two revisions of a question]

Comment: 1) Paste your code in the box 2) Put 3 backticks above your code 3) Put 3 backticks below your code.  You don't need AI for this.

Comment: Alternatively, 1) paste your code in the box 2) select the code 3) click the bracket button in the editor. Just because AI is big and fancy doesn't mean everything needs to use it

Comment: [In the revisions of your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76797612/revisions) (aka the edit history) you can click on ["Side-by-side Markdown"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiiDV.png) which shows the exact characters that were inserted/removed. Instead of just the rendered visualisation.

Comment: You're not the only person, by a wide margin, to make a similar mistake, but you might be the first to come to meta with it.  Could you explain the process by which you ended up with the formatting you did (especially the many instances of "your text"), and in what way the UI was misleading?  It might be helpful in making the UI clearer.

Comment: For the more experienced users here, note that this is regarding the Ask Wizard (which uses the Stacks Editor) and not the editor most of us are used to.

Comment: AI always helps except when it doesn't. In fact, it's just like everything else.

Comment: For context, [this is the question OP is referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76797612/1).

Comment: *"Does AI artificial intelligence not help?"* - It can do some wicked things with audio and video manipulation. Yesterday I saw Arnold Schwarzenegger break down a door with an axe and yell "Here's Arnie!" But on the topic of making it so you yourself never have to think again... no, we're at least a decade away from that still. You'll just have to make an effort until then.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I should use the AltGr+7 key to add signs like ``` above and below the code.
The name of this sign (backtick) I have never died before in my life. There is no Hungarian translation!


```
Import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

win.tittle('Markdown formatting')

win.mainloop()
```

This is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly format you code, you can do one of the following:

1. **Precede each line of code by 4 whitespaces**
2. **Put 3 backticks (```) above and below your code**

For method #1, make sure there is an empty line between any text and your code.

If you use an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) like Visual Studio, you can press Ctrl+A to select all your code and then press the tab button to move it to the right by 4 whitespaces. Then simply press Ctrl+C to copy it and Ctrl+V to paste it into your question or answer.

Remember, if your IDE doesn't follow the mentioned behavior and erased your code, you should be able to restore it by pressing Ctrl+Z (Undo).

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I should use the AltGr+7 key to add signs like ``` above and below the code.
The name of this sign (backtick) I have never died before in my life. There is no Hungarian translation!


```
Import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

win.tittle('Markdown formatting')

win.mainloop()
```

This is OK?